# How give trans method in js when using localization (laravel 5.3)

Tags: javascript, laravel, localization

I am working on localization and using `{{trans('pro.alert.error')}}` In my php and now i want to use it in js file also there its not working how to write there 
I am using same in my .php file as

```
$('#msg-text').html('{{trans('pro.alert.error')}}');
```

Here its working fine but not in .js

my **js** code is as

```
invalidHandler: function(e, t) {
   $('#msg-text').html('You have errors');
},
```

I want to change this text in html  to as `{{trans('pro.alert.error')}}`
But its not working here

Please help how to fix it

Comment: Try using double quotes : 

    `var err = "{{ trans('pro.alert.error') }}";`

Answer (score 1):

Don not mix JS and PHP. I'd recommend you to put translation into hidden input:

```
{!! Form::hidden('error', trans('app.you-have-errors')) !!}
```

And then get this data in JS:

```
$('#msg-text').html($('[name="error"]').value());
```

Comment: its looks fine .. should i use your 1st line in my .php file where i am printing errors?

Comment: First line should be in `.blade.php`, it will create hidden input with translated string. In JS you just getting printed string. Using same way you can pass another errors, messages or data to JS.

Comment: its sying form not found in my blade.php .. please tell my can i do as 

<input type="hidden" name ="error"  trans('app.you-have-errors') >

Comment: Oh. It should be `<input type="hidden" name="error" value="{{ trans('app.you-have-errors') }}">` If you'll use it just for JS, you could use `id` instead of `name`

Comment: please update your answer i did it as input hidden ...
how to pass it in js .. its not working in js as you define in your answer above

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be:

```
invalidHandler: function(e, t) {
   $('#msg-text').html("{{ trans('pro.alert.error') }}");
},
```

If you want it in your .js file, you can use:

`Route::get('/myfile.js', 'JSController@customJS');`

Controller:
    public function customJS() {
        return view('js.custom');
    }

View:

`$('#msg-text').html("{{ trans('pro.alert.error') }}");`

When you include the `<script src="{{ asset('/myfile.js') }}"></script>` in your code this should work!

Hope this works!

Comment: i said i try this its printing as it is {{ trans('app.messages.error') }} intstead of error

Comment: You edited you question, but now I understand. You cannot use `blade tags` in .js, you can use inline javascript, that will work. Otherwise you need my answer in above.

Comment: @recoverymen did you test this?

Comment: i dont't want extra route etc i done without it thanx